# Subscriber with member callback function

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to subscribe to the model msgs in gazebo, however I cannot bind the callback function in a correct way. This is the code:

```
class WorldInterface : public WorldPlugin

{

public:


    void messageReceived1(const msgs::Model& _msg)
    {
        std::cout << "Got the message!" << std::endl;
        modelLoaded_ = true;
    }

    void Load(physics::WorldPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {

        transport::NodePtr node(new transport::Node());
        node->Init();


        transport::SubscriberPtr modelSub =
                node->Subscribe("~/model/info", std::bind(&gazebo::WorldInterface::messageReceived1, this, _1));

.....
}
};
```

The error I get is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘gazebo::transport::Node::Subscribe(const char [13], std::_Bind_helper<false, void (gazebo::WorldInterface::*)(const gazebo::msgs::Model&), gazebo::WorldInterface*, boost::arg<1>&>::type)’
     node->Subscribe("~/model/info", std::bind(&gazebo::WorldInterface::messageReceived1, this, _1));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16207/subscriber-with-member-callback-function/) by [jelavice](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3256/jelavice/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try changing your subscriber to this:

`node->Subscribe("~/model/info", &WorldInterface::messageReceived1, this));`

And your callback to this:

`void messageReceived1(ConstModelPtr &_msg)`

See an example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/bae84f76b4ad7a6a7cecaeb3e76e545b8c8d5f3e/plugins/BlinkVisualPlugin.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#BlinkVisualPlugin.cc-137).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jelavice](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3256/jelavice/) on 2017-05-20**:
That solved the error, thanks.

**Comment by [jelavice](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3256/jelavice/) on 2017-05-20**:
Btw can you think of any good reason my plugin is not receiving any messages? As far as I understood, there should be a message broadcasted on "~/model/info" topic any time a model is inserted in to a simulation. I insert the model with parent->InsertModelFile() however no message is received + model count in the world stays exactly the same. I am doing this in the Load function for the world plugin.

**Comment by [mstniy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29953/mstniy/) on 2020-08-08**:
You probably need to create the node in *Init*, not *Load*